# Interactions preserving separability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

Consider the interaction (described by a unitary matrix U) of two qubits initially in a separable state |ab⟩ = |a⟩ ⊗ |b⟩, such that after interaction the composite system is in state U|ab⟩.

Are there unitary matrices U for which U|ab⟩ is also separable, independent of |ab⟩?

If so: How can these matrices be characterized?

If not so: How can the separable states |ab⟩ for which also U|ab⟩ is separable, be characterized?

Comment: Some such matrices are those of the form $U=U_1\otimes U_2$ for unitaries $U_1$ and $U_2$. These take the separable state $\left|a\right\rangle\otimes\left|b\right\rangle$ to the separable state $\left(U_1\left|a\right\rangle\right)\otimes \left(U_2\left|b\right\rangle\right)$.

However these aren't all such matrices. For example there's also the map taking $\left|a\right\rangle\otimes\left|b\right\rangle$ to $\left|b\right\rangle\otimes\left|a\right\rangle$.

Comment: Related anecdote: the fourier transform can turn separable states into entangled states, but every classical input does happen to get mapped to a separable state. Incrementing the input rotates the outputs individually. For me that was an example of separability-under-operations not behaving in an expected way.

Comment: What is a "classical input"?

Answer (score 1):

Any linear operation $U$ which maps all product states $|a\rangle_A|b\rangle_B$ onto product states must be of the form
$$
U \equiv (U_A\otimes U_B)\mathbb F\ ,
$$
where $U_A$ and $U_B$ act independently on the two parts of the system, and $\mathbb F$ swaps the two parts, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb F:|a\rangle_A|b\rangle_B \mapsto |b\rangle_A|a\rangle_B\ .
$$
This is proven in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407118 (Sec. II C, Result 1).